# Why Quaternion rotations are smoother than Euler rotation?

Tags: quaternions

I have stumble upon this phrase several times but can't fully understand what it refers to. "Quaternion rotations are **smoother** than Euler rotations."

I understand that the gimbal lock problem with Euler gets fixed with Quaternions. But why the rotation becomes smoother? Is it because there is no more strange axis rotations happening, thus the rotation happens directly without consequences?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give an example where you saw this? I can only understand this to make sense in, perhaps, the context of *interpolating* a rotation (which is common in, say, computer graphics applications) rather than for rotations in general.

Comment: Yes, exactly, in that context. I've seen it in 3d object rotation explanations. Perhaps I should have posted my question in the computer graphics community, sorry.